# Build array of objects from params hash after Transaction block fails, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions

I have a form where a user can update multiple resources at the same time.  The transaction block makes the form atomic: if one validation fails for any of the resources being updated, then none of the resources get updated, and active record *rollsback* all changes.

When transaction fails, I want to render the form again, display the same input that the user entered along with errors next to each of the error input fields  which prevented the transaction from going through.

The transaction block works.  What I am having trouble with is building the array of objects from the params log.  Each index of the array should contain a hash which holds key/value pairs of all the attributes of a specific resource.

**UDPATE: BELOW IS THE ANSWER CODE THANKS TO THE RESPONSES**

**Code:**

```
def update_multiple
  begin
    User.transaction do
      params[:users].each do |k, v|
      User.find(k).update!(v)
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Update Successful"
    redirect_to :users and return
  end
  rescue
    @users = []
    params[:users].each do |k,v|
      @users.push(User.new({:id => k}.merge(v))) 
    end
    flash[:error] = "Errors found"
    render :edit_multiple and return
  end
end
```

And for good measure, here is what the passed in parameters looks like in the log.  This transaction fails because the name attribute must be at least 3 characters long.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xyz=", "users"=>{"15"=>
{"name"=>"Neil", "age"=>"11"}, "16"=>{"name"=>"z", "age"=>"33"}, "17"=>
{"name"=>"John", "age"=>"99"}}, "commit"=>"Submit Changes"}
```

Thanks in advance! Any way to write this code better in ruby is much appreciated as well.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your view. What's your view code look like?

Comment: @Micah Did a minor change: id = u[count]. Error says "When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument"

Comment: You can't used `id = object` you need to set it to a hash, in this case `:id => u[count]` although what I'm looking at is not going to work correctly from what I can tell. You only ever use one id from each `user_id` object, but you have an iterator that increments anyways?

Comment: That's true that doesn't seem right.  I changed it but what I currently have doesn't work either.

Comment: I think I see what you're doing wrong there so I'll create an answer real fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you're trying to iterate through a list of objects in your params using a for_each and an external iterator, you really don't want to do that. I'd suggest something like this:

```
params[:users].each do |k,v|
  # k is the "key" of each user while v is the values associated with each key
  @users.push(User.new(:id => k, v)
  # I'm doing this in my head so you might need:
  # @users.push(User.new({:id => k}.merge(v)) 
  # if you start getting errors about looking for a proper hash or something
  # I can't remember how good Rails/Ruby is at recognizing nested hashes
end
```

That should produce a new user for each user object passed in using the ID provided and the values associated with each value.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, though I am having trouble making it work.  I updated the code above to reflect my changes.

Comment: @Neil if you're getting undefined method errors, then you never initialized `@users`.  You need to set it to something that supports the `push` method, I assume an array?